# Subir select dentro de un subir archivos

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Hola buenas tardes como se encuentran queria pedir ayudar de como podria subir un select dentro de un subir archivos osea subir el select y los archivos con un solo boton este es el codigo que tengo ahorita 
este es mi javascript

```
//funcion cargueArchivo
    $(':file').change(function()
     {
         //obtenemos un array con los datos del archivo
         var file = $("#imagen")[0].files[0];
         //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
         var fileName = file.name;
         //obtenemos la extensión del archivo
         fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
         //obtenemos el tamaño del archivo
         var fileSize = file.size;
         //obtenemos el tipo de archivo image/png ejemplo
         var fileType = file.type;
         //mensaje con la información del archivo
         showMessage("<span class='info'>Archivo para subir: "+fileName+", peso total: "+fileSize+" bytes.</span>");
     });




    $('#cargueArchivo').click(function(){
        //información del formulario
        var formData = new FormData($("#frmFormulario")[0]);
        var message = "";
        //hacemos la petición ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            // Form data
            //datos del formulario
            data: formData,
            //necesario para subir archivos via ajax
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //mientras enviamos el archivo
            beforeSend: function(){
                message = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo la imagen, por favor espere...</span>");
                showMessage(message);
            },
            //una vez finalizado correctamente
            success: function(data){
                message = $("<span class='success'>La imagen ha subido correctamente.</span>");
                showMessage(message);
                if(isImage(fileExtension))
                {
                    //$(".showImage").html("Imagen Cargada: <img height ='500' src='/../files/"+data+"' />");


                    //alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                    $.post('php/imagen_actualiza.php', data, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                        //alert('Data2: ' + data2);
                        $(".showImage").html(data2);

                    });
                    return;

                                        //showMessage("");
                                        //$('#cargueArchivo').prop('disabled',false);
                                        //$(':files').prop('disabled',false);

                }
            },
            //si ha ocurrido un error
            error: function(){
                message = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
                showMessage(message);
            }
        });
    });
    //FIN funcion cargueArchivo
    //funcion incumplimiento

    //FIN funcion incumplimiento

}
```

ESTE ES MI PHP

```
//comprobamos que sea una petición ajax
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{

    //obtenemos el archivo a subir
    $file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

    //comprobamos si existe un directorio para subir el archivo
    //si no es así, lo creamos
    if(!is_dir("../files/"))
        mkdir("../files/", 0777);

    //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
    if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"../files/".$file))
    {
        sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
        echo $file;//devolvemos el nombre del archivo para pintar la imagen
        //Insertar BD
            $image =  $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            // Get text
            //$image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

            //$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text','". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] ."')";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text','". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] ."')";
            $result = $link->query($sql);
            // execute query
            //mysqli_query($db, $sql);

       //Fin.Insertar BD
    }
}else{
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
}
?>
```

Y ESTE SELECT QUE VISUALIZA

```
<?php
//session_start();
//include "conectar.php";
$sql_img = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id_inspeccion = ". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'];
//$link = conectar();
$num_rows_img =0;
$result_img = $link->query($sql_img);
$vector_resultado_img  = array();    
$content_img = '';

//$num_rows_img = $num_rows_img + NVL($result_img->num_rows,0);

if (isset($result_img->num_rows)) {

$content_img = '<table  width="55%"  rules="all" border="1" align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>                                
<th>images</th>
<th></th>
</thead>';

while($row_img = $result_img->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
    $content_img .= '<tr><td> <img height ="500" src="files/'. $row_img["image"] .'" /></td>'; ///imagen                                        
    $content_img .=  '<td>'. $row_img["image_text"] . '</td>';  //descripcion
    $content_img .=  '</tr>';   
    }
}
$content_img .=  '</table>';

 echo $content_img;
?>
```

[image: aca esta la imagen :)]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: y cual es el error en tu codigo o que es lo que no logras hacer con el

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, imagino que lo que quieres es al darle al subit, pasar al php un sql, es decir el string del sql?

En caso afirmativo, en tu formData le haces un `append` y metes ahí la string.

```
var consulta = "SELECT lo que sea FROM tabla WHERE x";
formData.append("consultasql", consulta);
```

Comment: si amigo cuando yo le de subir imagen envie los dos datos el select y la foto a la base de datosy  las muestre

Comment: Y no puedes hacer la consulta en el archivo del php? sin tener que mandar un sql? Básicamente porque es inseguro.

Comment: es que amigo ellos deben selecionar una opcion o un combobox y yo quiero que ese combobox se suba tambien con el boton subir archivos para quese impriman por ejemplo yo en el combobox escojo la opcion feliz entonces tengo que poner una foto feliz y darle subir archivo y se muestren las dos